# SQL any of 1st list IN 2nd

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

SQL Server 2005.

I have 2 lists:

1. ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
2. ('d', 'e', 'f', 'g')

I need to make a WHERE clause with these 2 inside a dynamic SQL string, something like:

```
 select *
 from tbl
 where ... afewconditionshere ...
      AND anyitemfrom[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')] is inside [('d', 'e', 'f', 'g')]
```

it looks kinda weird, but I get this data from a 3rd party, cannot make too big changes

the lists would always have < 20 items inside

UPDATE

a,b,c,d,e,f,g are like security things not related to the table in any way, the idea is that if you have this anyitemfrom[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')] is inside [('d', 'e', 'f', 'g')] then you are able to view the records returned, otherwise no records should be returned

yes this condition should basically return true or false

Comment: Both these lists are something that come from external data (data not found in the database)? If so, these conditions should be met _outside_ of SQL, not appended as a new condition. (Unless I am misunderstanding the question). However, SQL does have an `IN` clause. e.g. `WHERE mycolumn IN ('a','b','c','d')`

Comment: If you are building the SQL dynamically, and the content of both lists is known to your program at the time you prepare your dynamic SQL string, wouldn't the `anyitemfrom[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')] is inside [('d', 'e', 'f', 'g')]` condition reduce to a simple `true` or `false` answer? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Swoosh: Are any of the items a-g database-dependant? If not, why do you want to do this in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out

i used something like :

```
 CREATE TABLE #t (UserName VARCHAR(50))

 DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
 SELECT @sql = 'INSERT INTO #t SELECT ''' + REPLACE(@UserList, ',', ''' UNION SELECT ''') + ''''
 PRINT (@sql)
 EXEC (@sql)

 SELECT * FROM #t

 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE #t END
```

for both lists
then I was able to join them, and use the join's recordcount

Comment: This is SQL injection vulnerable by hacking the UserName.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, it seems if you perform one IN (), then a second IN() on the filtered data set, you should get what you're looking for:

```
select * from
(
select * from tbl
where ... afewconditionswhere ...
and anyitemfrom in('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
) as derived
where derived.anyitemfrom in ('d', 'e', 'f', 'g')
```

Comment: If the values are not static, you can always pass 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', in as parameters to your procedure? If so, then you can still do IN() of IN() on table variables, as one idea. Either that or you can use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @cmd varchar(2000), @list1 varchar(100), @list2 varchar(100)

select @list1 = "('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')", @list2 = "('d', 'e', 'f', 'g')"

select @cmd =
'select * from
(
select * from tbl
where ... afewconditionswhere ...
and anyitemfrom in ' + @list1 + '
) as derived
where derived.anyitemfrom in ' + @list2


exec(@cmd)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 WHERE (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM ( select 'a' union all select 'b' union all select 'c' union all select 'd'
                 intersect
                 select 'd' union all select 'e' union all select 'f' union all select 'g'
               )
       ) > 0
```